# using different class for <a> links

Tags: css, fonts, colors, hyperlink

I want to use a different font color for a link in the body text versus in the footer area. I added this in

```
.footer-widgets a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: #6fabad;
 }
```

The body text is

```
a, a:link, a:visited {
   color: #6fabad;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

The body text is still showing as the footer font color.  How can I fix this?

Comment: please provide your HTML

Comment: Because they're the same color? They're both `#6fabad` in your code.

Comment: If your footer is outside the `<body>` do `body a:link{ code }`. Also the `.footer-widgets` has to be before all of the elements you add after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

> If the colors are different your code will not work:

Both links will be the same color as the body style. because the `.footer-widgets` style will be over right by the`a:link`style.

```css
.footer-widgets a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #6fabad;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#"> hi</a>

  <div class="footer-widgets">
    <a href="#"> hi</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

**You have change your CSS to this :**

So that the `a:link` will be over right by `.footer-widgets a:link` and the `a:visited` by `.footer-widgets a:visited` only then you code will be 100% working.

```css
.footer-widgets a,
.footer-widgets a:link,
.footer-widgets a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #6fabad;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#"> hi</a>

  <div class="footer-widgets">
    <a href="#"> hi</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I've got the body link set to #6fabad, (a teal green) that's what the web inspector tools say, but it's still showing up as black in Firefox on Mac. Seems to be a Mac/Windows/browser issue, the colors of the links have no consistency between machines and browsers.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @janburg Am using Mac as well so there is no such bug, but did you check my fiddle it working perfectly right.?